# jQuery Widget Plugin: Calling an optional function gives "cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a small plugin that creates and shows a new div when a link is clicked on. Hides the div when it is clicked on again. I am basing it on the upcoming jQuery UI Tooltip plugin. The specific function of the plugin doesn't matter too much at the moment but it is throwing the error below when i run it.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

Full code and testing enviroment can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/mwillmott/LRrZU/

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in this string:

```
$(this.element).on("click", this.open);
```

when event handling your method "open" have "this == this.element" NOT YOUR object.

Fix your problem:

```
$(this.element).on("click", $.proxy(this.open, this));
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LRrZU/1/)

PS: Your code contain undefined _bind method.